# I am trying to install minGW but my environmental path is different and I can't edit?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, mingw32, mingw-w64

I am using notepad++ to compile c++ and am trying to install MinGW, but I am having issues here are the screen shots.

**This is what I get when I highlight and then click edit in the enviormental variables.**
[image]

**This is what the tutorials show I am supposed to get**[image]

Am I not seeing something? what can I do?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using TDM GCC http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/ which will set up your path for you. If you feel you must mess with the path yourself, use a tool like https://www.rapidee.com/en/about which is a billion times better tham Microsofts sad utility.

Comment: The 'variable value' for 'Path' is longer than what is shown in that small window. Try using the keyboard arrows to move inside. Add `;c:\mingw\bin`to that value (note the semicolon ';') being "mingw" the folder where you installed mingw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window depends on your windows version, just add it manually.

In the window "Variable value" as you posted, go to start and add MinGW bin path with ';' like this:

C:\dev\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel...

now you should open your cmd and check it (version etc.).